Not All Variables Bound
I have clob variable which is storing the sql statement to execute and I am assigning the sql output in table type object.
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO result_table;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LOOKUP_RECORD AS OBJECT (
  op_unit          VARCHAR2(100),
  region           VARCHAR2(100),
  part_no          VARCHAR2(50),
  inv_org          VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LOOKUP_TABLE AS TABLE OF LOOKUP_RECORD;

Getting error:

not all Variable bound

while calling the function
kindly suggest how can I debug to fix this?
it should call the execute immediate statement and store the output of v_sql in result_table.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the complete code you are using as EXECUTE IMMDIATE should be in a PL/SQL block and the v_sql and result_table variables are never declared, the CREATE TYPE statements should not be in a PL/SQL block and there are no bind variables so it is unclear what you are doing or what is unbound. Also make sure you include the value of v_sql and any relevant CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for the sample data necessary to run your dynamic SQL. We cannot debug code we cannot see and the code you have presented does not make sense.
